# Can we pass multiple params in a route ? vue-router - vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

Can we pass more than 1 param in vue-router ?
I have a list of movies and when i click on one of them, it shows the movie details by fetching the data from an Api
My route for the movie details is like this:

```
{
      path: '/movies/:id',
      name: 'movie-details',
      component: MovieDetailsView,
      props: true
}
```

Sending the props with RouterLink:

```
<RouterLink :to="{ name: 'movie-details', params: { id: movie.id } }" class="link">
```

Everything works fine, but what i want is, to send the ID and the SLUG of a single movie so i can use the id
to fetch the data from the API( api accept only id to fetch data ) and the slug to use it in the route, cause i don't want to show the movie's id.

I tried something like

```
<RouterLink :to="{ name: 'movie-details', params: { id: movie.id, slug: movie.slug } }" class="link">
```

then getting the slug in my component from props

```
const props = defineProps(['id','slug'])
```

but the slug is always undefined

How it can be done ? is it even possible ?

Comment: try with `$route.push({ name: 'movie-details', params: { id: movie.id, slug: movie.slug } })`, obviously change RouterLink to normal link tag

Comment: we cannot access the $ in the composition api,

Comment: so like https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html `const $route = useRoute()`

Comment: well, i just got it now.
basically vue-router deleted the possibility were you could send params that are not included in the path, and there's multiple alternatives to it
https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22